# Accidentally deleted /var/log. How can I fix it?

Tags: apache2, log

Accidentally I deleted my `/var/log` folder

How can I recreate that folder again (and have logging work).

I have some issues with Apache, and I can't see any logs because the `/var/log` folder don't exist any more.

Comment: With my Ubuntu 20.04.x, after rebooting the /var/log gets created.  However not all directories that are needed get created, or they are created but are created with incorrect ownership and/or permissions. But even /var/log getting recreated automatically probably doesn't help you much with getting Apache2 logging again, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

In my system I have this:

```
% ls -lad /var/log
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 12288 Nov  8 16:01 /var/log
```

So my first try would be to recreate that and reboot... (**no guarantees: never tried that, and I have no time now to set up a VM just to try it...**)

```
sudo mkdir /var/log
sudo chmod 755 /var/log
```

I hope that the various daemons will repopulate the directory correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the best answer would be ... well, don't do that. And if you did do that, just restore from a recent backup of your system.

You have been doing system backups using something like timeshift, right?

Ok, assuming that is not the case (which is why even I myself have ended up here at this post), ... the answer is that you might be able to get away with recreating the /var/log directory and various other directories and be fine from there.  Other services that you have installed (e.g., nginx, teamviewer) may not work without (and/or will not properly log) without manually re-creating the necessary directores (or, uninstalling and re-installing those services).

The following commands will work to re-create any directories missing (but needed for logging to work) and to then configure them with the default ownerships and permissions.  If you prefer to use a script, see [my Snippet](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2199379) with that instead.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log
sudo chown root:syslog /var/log
sudo chmod 765 /var/log
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/journal
sudo chown root:systemd-journal /var/log/journal
sudo chmod 2755 /var/log/journal
sudo setfacl -Rnm g:adm:rx,d:g:adm:rx /var/log/journal
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/cups
sudo chown root:root /var/log/cups
sudo chmod 755 /var/log/cups
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/unattended-upgrades
sudo chown root:adm /var/log/unattended-upgrades
sudo chmod 750 /var/log/unattended-upgrades
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/hp
sudo chown root:root /var/log/hp
sudo chmod 755 /var/log/hp
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/hp/tmp
sudo chown root:lp /var/log/hp/tmp
sudo chmod 775 /var/log/hp/tmp
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/speech-dispatcher
sudo chown speech-dispatcher:root /var/log/speech-dispatcher
sudo chmod 700 /var/log/speech-dispatcher
```

For nginx:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/nginx
sudo chown root:adm /var/log/nginx
sudo chmod 755 /var/log/nginx
sudo nginx -t
```

**After** running these commands, **restart your system**. This is because various services needing these changes have already started and most won't automatically resume logging without being restarted (which, a person could do but I don't know all the services affected and don't plan to document the steps for that when simply doing a system restart solves the problem).

---

Note: There are services that will automatically create the directories as needed (e.g., /var/log/apt, /var/log/gdm3, /var/log/private) and get created properly (i.e., with correct ownership and permissions), so I have not included the commands to manage those directories.

These procedures were performed and tested on Ubuntu 20.04.03.  I have no idea which other versions of Ubuntu or Debian for which these procedures would be correct.

Also, this is specifically for Ubuntu / Debian.  Other distros (e.g., Red Hat / Fedora) will have some differences (e.g., the acl for /var/log/journal would include the group wheel as well).

And finally, if you were not using defaults or had performed security hardening on your system, these procedures may not be exactly what you want as they will revert back to the defaults used at installation (or, at least, the defaults as far as I had seen on my system which I used to identify what changes were needed).

Comment: **REQUESTING A REVIEW FROM A COMPETENT SYSADMIN**

This question has gone 8 years without any additional answer than one other one which is incomplete, so I have taken a shot at it, myself.

I have done a sanity check using these steps but a review by someone with more experience might find something I have wrong or have missed.

Comment: Also, if anyone has Apache2 installed, ... what are the default ownership and permissions (since that specifically is what OP was asking for)?  I will edit my answer to include that, just as I have for nginx.